# Launch Twitter app from another app in Android

Tags: android, cordova, twitter

I'm trying to launch Twitter app from my Cordova app on Android but it always open inapp browser, i use the same code on IOS and it work perfectly.
This is the code i'm using:

```
window.open('twitter://user?screen_name=MyTwitterUserName', '_system');
```

Before i execute the above code i check if Twitter app is already installed, i have installed it on my phone but still open it in browser, the same code as i said before works without any problem on IOS, i also tried this code but none of them works on Android.

```
window.open('twitter://user?user_id=MyTwitterID', '_system');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should launch the Twitter app.

```
Intent intent = null;
try {
    // get the Twitter app if possible
    this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=USERID"));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // no Twitter app, revert to browser
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/USERID_OR_PROFILENAME"));
}
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Try using this plugin, too: https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp

Comment: thanks but i'm using Cordova and `twitter://user?user_id=USERID` didn't work for me

Comment: i didn't use any plugin for it. it open like a normal link, for facebook `'fb://profile/name'` for youtube `vnd.youtube://www.youtube.com/channel`, they all work fine except for Twitter, Twitter works fin on IOS but not on Android